# Eclipse Git (EGit) unable to clone Git repository

Tags: git, egit

Basically, I can't find a workable URI for the EGit Clone Git Repository dialog.

[image: One attempt]

Using protocol git, just as from my command-line clone operation, I've tried various URIs with unsatisfactory results. Sometimes, I can't click the Next button:

```
git://af-blackpearl.site
git:af-blackpearl.site:myproject
```

In other cases, I try (and I can click the Next button):

```
git:af-blackpearl.site/myproject[.git] (with or without extension)
```

but, I get:

```
Cannot list the available branches.
Reason:
git:af-blackpearl.site/rest-server:ProxyHTTP: java.io.IOException:
 proxy error: Service Unavailable
```

When I try:

```
git://af-blackpearl.site/myproject[.git] (with or without extension)
git://af-blackpearl.site/
```

I always get something like:

```
Cannot list the available branches.
Reason:
git://af-blackpearl.site/myproject: Connection refused
```

Many thanks for any suggestion to follow up on.

**Useful Background**

- Git administrated using *gitolite*
- Git remote(s) on Linux host
- My "client" host, Linux, is running Eclipse Helios
- Been using Git via command line; works great

This question is specifically about using the EGit (Eclipse plug-in) dialog. It is not about Git, using Git or even installing the plug-in--all of which do not seem troublesome. Simply, I've long been using Git from the command line and am just trying to use the Eclipse-Git integration now.

In */etc/hosts*, I have a line:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx   af-blackpearl.site
```

for our local Git remote repository. Though I administer Git via a *gitolite-admin* project, the (physical, filesystem) path to the project I'd like to clone on af-blackpearl.site is

***/home/git/repositories/myproject.git***

From the command line, I'm used to cloning it from origin thus with consistent success:

```
$ git clone git:af-blackpearl.site:myproject
```

Despite looking at the EGit (Google-hosted) documentation and much Googling, I'm having trouble adapting this to the EGit Clone Git Repository dialog (reached thus):

```
File -> Import... -> Git -> Projects from Git -> Clone
```

Connection to remote:

```
russ@russ-elite-book:~> ssh git@af-blackpearl.site
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
hello russ, the gitolite version here is v2.0.1-2-g836faf9
the gitolite config gives you the following access:
     R   W     NavigationServlet
     R   W     gitolite-admin
     R   W     ivysample
     R   W     myproject
     R   W     seam-catch
Connection to af-blackpearl.site closed.
```

Comment: It really annoys me that this question was voted down w/o writing a comment as to why. Does that mean the downvoter had a solution, but did not bother to provide it?

Comment: It was probably downvoted by someone who was so in love with Git that they couldn't stand for someone to find something wrong with it.  Would've made more sense if there was an actual solution to this vexing problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the SSH protocol (I saw you use "ssh git@af-blackpearl.site"), you should choose "ssh" in protocol. The repository name is myproject (no `.git` part)

Comment: I may have mistyped something, but I assure you I've tried myriad variations on URI, protocol, username, etc. I've also worked over SSH2 settings, local key files, etc. It just doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: I apologize for not recognizing this as the answer back when posted. I abandoned eGit for the command line and just stopped caring. Additionally, we've moved on, after 18 months, from a Git server I set up to github.com. In the first case, the suffix .git was not/could not be used. In the second, it is required. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

I too had problems with this. But I found a solution presented here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html#clone_respository

In short, write URI: **git@** yourhost.com:repository instead of git:// This makes eclipse connect as user git instead of your username, but still use your private key.

I did not set any protocol, just as the article does not.

EDIT: Now I actually found that "J-16 SDiZ" posted quite the same answer. Although I didn't get it at that time.

Comment: I am remiss in visiting this question. I abandoned eGit in favor of the command line because I'm a command-line sort of guy anyway. Later, a colleague figured this out, but watching him wade through the Team menu and dialog boxes convinced me to stay with the command line which is more "typing" but far fewer steps. Yes, J-16 SDIZ and you have the answer to the original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems you describe connecting to remote git repositories through the EGit dialogs.

What I've ended up doing is still using the command line git tools to clone repos and stuff, and then import the repos into Eclipse as local repos. As far as I can tell that makes all of EGits functionality working perfectly, and I've used Eclipse to add, commit, push and change branches and all worked flawlessly.

I still use the command line tools for a lot of tasks, and this gives me the best of both worlds IMHO. But initially it bugged the hell out of me that I could not get EGit to clone remote repositories directly.

I know it's not a direct answer to your question, but Eclipse with EGit is fully functional without cloning remotely from within EGit.

Comment: I'm betting that this is the answer. The EGit community forum treated my question like a dead rat for a week (why I posted here). I will try the hybrid approach you suggest. Thanks.

Comment: There's gotta be a better solution, right?  I mean, almost everyone has to do this for each and every project.

Comment: Yeah, I know. :) But I haven't found a better way yet. Haven't looked in about a year either though.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using the full server path to your git repository.

I am in the process of implementing my first project using git. I am using the git service offered by my shared Linux hosting plan (1and1).

After a lot of trial and error I seem to be able to find the git repository if I use the full server path to it.

In my case:

My git repository was created at /project

The only path that seems to let me find the git repository is:

/homepages/foo/bar/htdocs/project/.git <- this is the full server path at 1and1.

I am using the SSH protocol.

It doesn't make sense that I have to use the full path because when I ssh to my account I get to my account home. But any other combination I tried doesn't work.

---

If you are curious to see the exact configuration I used to access my git repository in my shared host, check this question -> [Problems cloning 1and1 git repository in 1and1 shared Linux server with Eclipse EGit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327977/problems-cloning-1and1-git-repository-in-1and1-shared-linux-server-with-eclipse-e)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I checked the eclipse configuration of SSH2 and found it correctly points to the "~/.ssh"

The problem was that I did not have any keys there (id_rsa & id_rsa.pub)
I added them, tried again, I pulled successfully my github repo.