# Problems cloning 1and1 git repository in 1and1 shared Linux server with Eclipse EGit

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, shared-hosting, egit

I have just setup a git repository in my 1and1 shared hosting. 1and1 offers git as part of the Linux business package and I decided to use it instead of installing my own git.

When I do dir .git I can see the information inside the repository:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 foo ftpusers      23 Sep  6 19:41 HEAD
drwxr-xr-x   2 foo ftpusers       6 Sep  6 19:41 branches
-rw-r--r--   1 foo ftpusers      92 Sep  6 20:42 config
-rw-r--r--   1 foo ftpusers      73 Sep  6 19:41 description
drwxr-xr-x   2 foo ftpusers    4096 Sep  6 19:41 hooks
-rw-r--r--   1 foo ftpusers 1038768 Sep  6 19:41 index
drwxr-xr-x   2 foo ftpusers      20 Sep  6 19:41 info
drwxr-xr-x 260 foo ftpusers    8192 Sep  6 19:41 objects
drwxr-xr-x   4 foo ftpusers      29 Sep  6 19:41 refs
```

My repository is located at /project (full path at 1and1 is /homepages/foo/bar/htdocs/project)

When I try to access it using Eclipse EGit it says that the repository appears to be empty. See below what I have attempted so far:

```
Protocol: SSH
Port: 22
Host: example.com
Repository path: project

Error Message:
Cannot list available branches.
Reason: ssh://<username>@example.com:22/project: fatal '/project'
does not appear to be a git repository.
```

Then I tried changing the repository path:

```
Repository path: project/.git

Same error
```

Then I decided to try with the full path in my server:

```
Repository path: /homepages/foo/bar/htdocs/project/.git

New error: Source Git Repository is empty
```

So it seems that it finds the git repository. However it is showing as empty.

By the way, see below the commands I used to create the git repository in my shared 1and1 account:

from my account root:

```
mkdir project
cd project
cp -r ../example/* .
git init
git add .
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the result of a git log from the command line in the repository?  The files you see are created with `git init` and do not mean something has actually been commited.  It appears that you have staged files but not commited them.

Comment: @Andrew Myers - you are right... I executed two commands git init and git add. When I do the git log command I get - fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'
lines 1-1/1 (END)

Comment: @Andrew Myers - it is working now. I just had to commit the files. I guess I still have a long ways to go before being comfortable with git. Thank you. I voted your comment up. If you add it as an answer I will mark it resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the result of a git log from the command line in the repository? The files you see are created with git init and do not mean something has actually been committed. It appears that you have staged files but not committed them.  It's a fairly common mistake since most other Version Control Systems don't have an analogous step.  Once you start using it to build patches (using `git add -p` for example) it's invaluable.

Some resources for getting started with git:

[progit](http://progit.org/) is an excellent book that is freely available online.  It's written by one of the founders of github.

The [git community book](http://book.git-scm.com/) is another online book on git.  There is a lot of overlap between it and progit but it goes more in depth with certain things (such as its description of treeishes).

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. Most of the online tutorials on git talks about git init and git add. Until I saw your answer and searched specifically for git commit I didn't know I had to commit after adding. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if you are still having issues with the "does not appear to be a git repository." issue.

I ran into the same problem and I found a solution without having to type out the entire 'pwd' url.

It appears that when you use ssh commands remotely into 1and1, they are not being run from your account's home directory (which is strange).  You can force the lookup to start from your home directory like this.

```
ssh://<username>@example.com:22/~/project
```

Notice the '~'.  This will look for the project under your base path in 1and1.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did figure out how to address my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran across the same problem using Aptana Studio 3.

Using

```
ssh://u1234@domain.com/~/gitrepository
```

solved it for me (Using 1&1, replacing the obvious).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Git Tower on the Mac. I finally got it going with ...

```
ssh://username@sshuser.online.de/~/repository.git
```

This is kind of strange because if I login via ssh, I get redirected to the home directory and the repository.git is right 'there'.

But now it works!